# How to obtain a list of sheets excluding several of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get a list of my sheets, but excluding two or more, "QUERIES" and "CONFIG". I have used some code that I have found here and have tried to adapt it to my needs, but unfortunately after many attempts I have not been able to get the code to work, no doubt due to my limited programming skills. I give up and ask for your help. Thanks a lot. Here is the code:

```
function sheetList() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var shConfig = ss.getSheetByName("CONFIG");
    var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
    var numberOfSheets = allsheets.length;

// Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
    var exclude = ["QUERIES","CONFIG"];
        for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];

// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
        for (i=2;i<numberOfSheets;i++){
           shConfig.getRange("A"+i).setValue(sheet[i]);
    }
  } // end of loop
} // end of function
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in this condition: if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue; it should be if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName()) !== -1) continue;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some more details. Firstly, what API is this? I might guess Google Sheets, but you don't actually say so. Secondly, what is the result of the code you've shown - does it give an error, or just not the results you wanted? It will also help you and others follow the code more easily if you indent it consistently - the body of each if, for, etc should be indented one "step" (e.g. four spaces) more.

Comment: I totally agree with IMSoP's comments. I'm sorry. 1) Yes, the API is Google Sheets. 2) I am not getting any value at all. 3) I have tried to indent the code. Thanks for the feedback.